# How to update data in mysql after you logged in

Tags: php, mysql

After the person logged in to the session, i want to update his bio. Its a small project for about 20 people so I am not worried about sql injection.

There is two pages, the first being the signup/login. and the other one being the profile. i want to update the bio on the profile page. after i click the update button, it redirects to the correct page but ther is no change in the database.

```
 //This is the signup server side  

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'pt');

if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['lastname']);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
$password_1 =  $_POST['password_1'];
$password_2 = $_POST['password_2'];
$sex = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['sex']);


  if ($sex == "Select Sex:") {
array_push($errors, "select male or female");
  }

 $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' OR 
 email='$email' LIMIT 1";
 $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
 $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

 if ($user) {
 if ($user['username'] === $username) {
 array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
}

if ($user['email'] === $email) {
array_push($errors, "email already exists");
}
}

if (count($errors) == 0) {
$password = md5($password_1);

$query = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, username, email, 
 password, sex, bio)
 VALUES('$firstname', '$lastname','$username', '$email', '$password', 
 '$sex','')";

mysqli_query($db, $query);
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
header('location: profile.php');
  }
  }

   //here is the code on the profile side.
 ?>
  <?php
  session_start();


 if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

if (isset($_POST['update_user'])) {
$bio = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['bio']);
$query = "UPDATE users SET bio='$bio' WHERE username=$username";;
      header('location: profileclient.php');
    }
    }
?>
 <form method="post" action="profileclient.php">
 <div class="input-group">
 <input    type="text" name="bio">
 </div>
 <div class="input-group">
 <button type="submit" class="button" name="update_user"> update! 
 </button>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: `Its a small project for about 20 people so I am not worried about sql injection.` Famous last words. Every project tends to grow. And even if it doesn't; most attacks happen from the _inside_. You must *always* use parameterized queries, no exceptions. Even if it's not a targetted attack, you don't wan't your application crashing on someone named `D'Artagnan`

Comment: _small project for about 20 people so I am not worried about sql injection..._ Would it be okay if you loose the data of even those only 20 users?

Comment: You are not executing `"UPDATE users SET bio='$bio'...`

Comment: how do i execute the data?

Comment: _how do i execute the data?..._ How are you doing this with your `SELECT` and `INSERT` queries? ;)

Comment: check answer.I hope this will work fine

Comment: Your problem is SQL injection. The solution is to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has multiple problems. Let me list them out.

**Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

**Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Always `exit()` after `header('Location: ...');`

It looks like you have forgot to start your session in the sign-up file. Add `session_start()`.

You need to enable error reporting for mysqli. Use `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Here is your code fixed:

```
<?php

session_start();

//This is the signup server side

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'pt');

if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password_1 = $_POST['password_1'];
    $password_2 = $_POST['password_2'];
    $sex = $_POST['sex'];

    if ($sex == "Select Sex:") {
        array_push($errors, "select male or female");
    }

    $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? OR email=? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $user_check_query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $username, $email);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($user) {
        if ($user['username'] === $username) {
            array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
        }

        if ($user['email'] === $email) {
            array_push($errors, "email already exists");
        }
    }

    if (!$errors) {
        $password_hashed = password_hash($password_1, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $query = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, username, email, password, sex, bio)
            VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,'')";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $query);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssssss', $firstname, $lastname, $username, $email, $password_hashed, $sex);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        exit(header('location: profile.php'));
    }
}

//here is the code on the profile side.
?>
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['update_user'])) {
        $query = "UPDATE users SET bio=? WHERE username=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $query);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $_POST['bio'], $_SESSION['username']);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        exit(header('location: profileclient.php'));
    }
}
?>
<form method="post" action="profileclient.php">
<div class="input-group">
<input    type="text" name="bio">
</div>
<div class="input-group">
<button type="submit" class="button" name="update_user"> update! 
</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: great thank you. How can I use a login form using prepared statements?

Answer (score -1):

Try using 'id' attribute in your input tag alongside the 'name' attribute

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this code in your profile section

<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['update_user'])) {
            $bio = mysqli->escape_string($_POST['bio']);
            $query = "UPDATE users SET bio='$bio' WHERE username='$username'" or die(mysqli_error());
            $result = $db->query($query);
            header('location: profileclient.php');
        }
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="profileclient.php">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input    type="text" name="bio" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <button type="submit" class="button" name="update_user"> update! </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question and is suggesting incorrect code.